# Need help with processing attachments with GAE InboundMailHandler

Tags: google-app-engine, email, blobstore

I have properly implemented InboundMailHandler  and I'm able to process all other mail_message fields except mail_message.attachments. The attachment filename is read properly but the contents are not being saved in the proper mime_type

```
        if not hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
            raise ProcessingFailedError('Email had no attached documents')

        else:
            logging.info("Email has %i attachment(s) " % len(mail_message.attachments))

        for attach in mail_message.attachments:
            filename = attach[0]
            contents = attach[1]


        # Create the file
        file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type = "application/pdf")

        # Open the file and write to it
        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
            f.write(contents)

        # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
        files.finalize(file_name)

        # Get the file's blob key
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
        return blob_key

        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
```

`

When I try to display the imported pdf file by going to the url: '/serve/%s' % blob_info.key()
I get a page with what seems like encoded data, instead of the actual pdf file.

Looks like this:

`From nobody Thu Aug 4 23:45:06 2011 content-transfer-encoding: base64 JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9G bGF0ZURlY29kZSA+PgpzdHJlYW0KeAGtXVuXHLdxfu9fgSef2RxxOX2by6NMbSLalOyQK+ucyHpQ eDE3IkWKF0vJj81vyVf3Qu9Mdy+Z40TswqKAalThqwJQjfm1/Hv5tWzxv13blf2xK++el+/LL+X+ g/dtefq`

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Email's attachments are `EncodedPayload` objects; to get the data you should call the `decode()` method.

Try with:

```
# Open the file and write to it
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(contents.decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want attachments larger 1MB to be processed successfully, decode and convert to str:

```
#decode and convert to string
datastr = str(contents.decode())
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write(datastr[0:65536])
  datastr=datastr[65536:]
  while len(datastr) > 0:
    f.write(datastr[0:65536])
    datastr=datastr[65536:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer in this excellent blob post:
http://john-smith.appspot.com/app-engine--what-the-docs-dont-tell-you-about-processing-inbound-mail

This is how to decode an email attachment for GAE inbound mail:

```
        for attach in mail_message.attachments:
            filename, encoded_data = attach
            data = encoded_data.payload
            if encoded_data.encoding:
                data = data.decode(encoded_data.encoding)
```

Comment: Afaik the `if encoded_data.encoding` check is useless, the `decode` method internally does [exactly the same](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/mail.py&q=EncodedPayload%20%20package:http://googleappengine\.googlecode\.com&l=492).